# Trying to come up with a function to sort time slots according to the start time in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have an array of strings that represents time slots of some events

```js
const times = [ ['12:15', '14:00'], ['09:00', '10:00'], ['10:30', '12:00'] ]
```

They are not sorted and they have been all converted to 24 Hour Clock.

I am trying to come up with a function to sort it.

here is my attempt:

```js
function isT1EarlierThanT2(t1, t2) {
    const [h1, m1] = t1.split(':')
    const [h2, m2] = t2.split(':')
    if(h1 !== h2) {
        return h1 < h2
    } else {
        return m1 < m2
    }
}

const times = [ ['12:15', '14:00'], ['09:00', '10:00'], ['10:30', '12:00'] ]

times.sort(([startTimeA], [startTimeB]) => isT1EarlierThanT2(...[startTimeA, startTimeB]) )
```

but it seems like it is not sorting it correctly. I can't seem to find the reason. Can anyone help?

Comment: What's the desired output for the array you provided?

Comment: Are you just sorting by the first element in each of the time arrays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just compare strings since it's 24 hour clock and you are padding with 0.

This will order by the first time in each sub array.

```js
const times = [ ['12:15', '14:00'], ['09:00', '10:00'], ['10:30', '12:00'] ]

times.sort(([a], [b]) => a < b ? -1 : 1);

console.log(times)
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to split the strings. You can just rely on lexical comparison in this case:

```js
const times = [['12:15', '14:00'], ['09:00', '10:00'], ['10:30', '12:00']];

times.sort(([t1], [t2]) => t1 > t2 ? 1 : t2 > t1 ? -1 : 0);

console.log(times);
```